# WHM manager Account Creation Status: failed

Tags: dns, cluster-computing, account, whm

I am not able to create above account "mydomainname.com".

While attempting to create such account the following message appears

Account Creation Status: failed

(A DNS entry for mydomainname.com already exists. You must remove this DNS entry from all servers in the DNS cluster to proceed.)

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to removed DNS zone of your account from your server because it's already created on your server and due to that you are getting this issues.